# Scala collectons filter and sort a sequence with objects containing a map and then iterate over it

Tags: scala, sorting, collections, filter, collect

given an object:

```
 case class GT(code: String,names: Map[String, Option[String]]) {}
```

and

a list :

```
val gText = List(new GT("USB", Map("de" -> Some("a"), "en" -> Some("abc"), "fr" -> Some("ab"))),
                  new GT("Switch", Map("de" -> Some("abcdef"), "en" -> Some("b"), "fr" ->  
                          Some("abc"), "es" -> Some("abc"))),
                  new GT("PVC", Map("de" -> Some("abc"), "en" -> Some("bc"), "fr" -> Some("abcd"))))
```

I want to iterate over the gText List but dependent from the key of map "names" and in descending order of the length of each "names" map value.

First iteration should be in the following oder with the values for "de":

```
1. code: "Switch" & names.key="de" & names.value = Some("abcdef")
2. code: "PVC" & names.key="de" & names.value = Some("abc")
3. code: "USB" & names.key="de" & names.value = Some("a")
```

Second iteration should be in the following oder with the values for "en":

```
1. code: "USB" & names.key="en" & names.value = Some("abc")
2. code: "PVC" & names.key="en" & names.value = Some("bc")
3. code: "Switch" & names.key="en" & names.value = Some("b")
```

Third iteration should be in the following oder with the values for "fr":

```
1. code: "PCV" & names.key="fr" & names.value = Some("abcd")
2. code: "Switch" & names.key="fr" & names.value = Some("abc")
3. code: "Switch" & names.key="fr" & names.value = Some("ab")
```

Last iteration is for `names.key="es"`
`code="Switch"` & `names.key="es"` and `names.value = Some("abc")`

As mentioned above the main goal is to iterate the values for the same key of the different GT's dependent from the length of each value.

How can I do that. Maybe first of all I have to collect the key in an additional set and then filter and sortyBy. Please any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.
Ugur

Comment: "How can I do that in one iteration." - but your example gives four iterations. So I'm not sure what you're asking. Are the number and values of the country codes known in advance?

Comment: you don't need to use `new` with case classes

Comment: thx. One iteration is impossible. I wanted to know how to iterate only the values of one key which are sorted by length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me exactly what order of iteration you want, but here's another way of skinning the cat.

```
  val countrySet = gText.flatMap { _.names.keys }.toSet 
  for {
    c <- countrySet
    gc = gText.filter(_.names.contains(c))
    g <- gc.sortBy(_.names(c).get.length).reverse
  } println("country " + c + " " + g)
```

Get the set of countries. Then, iterate through those, filter the list to only those that have an entry for the current country, sort that list by the length of the corresponding value (reversed, to get descending length)

Comment: Thanks to you too Paul!

Answer (score 1):

```
val gtEntries = gText.flatMap( gt => gt.names.toList.map(entry => (gt.code, entry._1, entry._2)))
val gtEntriesByLang = gtEntries.groupBy(_._2)

for (lang <- gtEntriesByLang.keys.toList.sorted;
 gtEntry <- gtEntriesByLang(lang).sortBy(entry => -entry._3.map(_.length).getOrElse(0) ))
 {
    println(gtEntry)
 }
```

The first line 'flattens' the list of GTs into tuples of the form ("USB","en",Some("abc")).

The second line groups it by language i. e. "en" => List( ("USB","en",Some("abc"), ...)

The for comprehension goes through all the languages in descending order and then sorts the entries by the length of the values of the original name map (0 if the option is undefined; make it 1 if you want to be None different to "").

Comment: Thx, that is the perfect solution. I have tested it. Wonderful